# GTK# StatusIcon Icon not display

Tags: c#, macos, gtk#, xamarin-studio

I tried to adding icon in Windows Tray using below code in GTK# application. (I am using Xamarin Studio to develop GTK# application)

```
Statusbar status = new Statusbar ();
trayIcon = new StatusIcon();                
trayIcon.Pixbuf = new Gdk.Pixbuf ("TrayIcon.ico");
trayIcon.IconName="Tray Icon Name";
trayIcon.Visible = true;               
trayIcon.PopupMenu += trayIcon_PopupMenu;
trayIcon.Tooltip = "Tray Icon Tooltip";
```

Icon added and contextmenu also added but icon "TrayIcon.ico" not display on Windows.

And same application I tried on MAC OSX but icon not added at MAC OSX.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by removing below line from code.
**trayIcon.IconName="Tray Icon Name";**

I am not sure but i assume that IconName overwrite (trayIcon.Pixbuf) IconImage.

Comment: That's correct. `IconName` is for a special name from the [Icon Naming Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html) which will cause the icon to pick its image from the icon theme according to that name, and indeed overwrite your pixbuf.