# Gtk# task bar icon

Tags: c#, icons, gtk#, taskbar

I can't find any working example of how to set the task bar icon for a Gtk# application.

I already tested this code on Main method:

```
StatusIcon trayIcon = new StatusIcon(new Gdk.Pixbuf("iconpath"));
trayIcon.Visible = true;
```

and:

```
Gtk.Window.SetDefaultIconFromFile("iconpath");
```

without any successful result.

Comment: check this link sounds like the individual solved it answering their own question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858034/gtk-statusicon-icon-not-display

Comment: I already checked this code, but I don't understant it. This an other examples create objects that are not "attached" to any application object or property :S I think you have to create an object (StatusIcon) and set it to the application in some way....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StatusIcon`s are strictly for the system tray. Use `window.SetIconFromFile()`, not `SetDefaultIconFromFile()`.